"Picklist promotion is not completed" error without explanation
While trying to promote a custom Account picklist field to a global value set, Salesforce gave me this error:

Picklist promotion is not completed

without any additional information. So, not helpful. I can think of a number of things that could go wrong:

A global value set with that name already exists
Something else is wrong with the name of the global value set that you try to create
???


In my case, the name that I picked for the global value set was too long. But Salesforce did not tell me that.
Feel free to add additional causes of global value set creation failure to the list in the question. Or how you can find out what the cause is of the error.

The max length of Global Value Set name is 40 chars, but unfortunately the input field used while promoting a picklist to a Global Value Set is limited to 255 chars. Maybe it's worth adding it to the answer
